# How to stop a bat file from running if there is no response

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file that I created, it adds keys to the windows registry and then calls another bat file, QGIS.bat (this bat file starts an application called QGIS).

It works most of the time but every now and then, when it calls QGIS.bat nothing happens, the command window stays open but QGIS (started by the QGIS.bat file) will not start.
In the command window(cmd) all it says is call .\usbgis\apps\qgis\bin\qgis.bat

(Just a note QGIS is a portable application that runs from a USB memory stick, might that be part of the problem?)

So my question. Is there a way you can terminate a bat file if it douse not close in 3 min or if the other bat file douse not start?

Thanks,

Comment: Add a loop in QGIS.bat so it runs every 10 seconds or so using tasklist to check if your program is running. Each time it does increment a variable until it reaches 30 and if it does exit with an error code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm talking about in my comment:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set sPath=C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer
set sprog=iexplore.exe
set inc=0

:loop
if exist "%sPath%\%sProg%" (echo %sProg%) else exit /b
set /a inc+=1
if "!inc!" equ "30" (Echo Exiting & exit /b)
for /f %%a in (
  'tasklist /NH /FI "Imagename eq %sProg%"^|findstr /i "INFO:"') do (
     if not errorlevel 1 (
       ping -n 11 127.0.0.1>nul
       goto :loop
     )
)
```

Obviously change the path and file to match yours. I just needed something for testing here.